# swich case pregunta básica

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a = 10000;

main ()
{
    int q = 60, w = 120, e= 200;
    int c;
    int l;
    printf ("SEDAN");
    printf ("\n <<60 litros>>");
    printf ("\nIngresa el auto a llenar:");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    
    
    switch (1)
    {
        case 1: 
        {
            c=a-q;
            printf("%d", c);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            c=c-w;
            printf("%d", c);
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

No me maten, pero estoy terminando la opción uno, da  el resultado deseado pero no vuelve a preguntar que se desea hacer ¿Qué le falta?. Ósea se que si no esta listo el case 2 no se va a realizar la operación, pero estoy probando el case 1 da el resultado y después da para presionar <kbd>Enter</kbd> y cerrarlo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues tu codigo como texto para que pueda ser copiado de manera facil :)

Comment: Debe estar en un ciclo `for` o `while` para que vuelva a preguntar.

Comment: the falta un ciclo para que vuelva a preguntar,

Comment: Gracias, tengo que hacer el ciclo por cada case o con 1  ciclo abarca todo?

Comment: Estoy checando tu codigo y no logro comprender lo que intentas hacer (me refiero a los swtich case). Igual te adjunto lo que he intentado.

Comment: Estoy intentando simular una bomba de gasolina que se esta vaciando (con las opciones swicht) estoy probando con el case 1  para que pregunte al usuario  si desea llenar un sedan con 60 litros de gasolina (q), esta en teoría restaría el valor de la bomba de gasolina(a) para llenar el auto, el resultado "c" (a-q) restablecería el valor de "a" y permitiria segur restando

Answer (score 0):

para que puedas repetir el menú, lo único que debes agregar es un ciclo `do{}while()`, y la [Doc de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/do-while-statement-c?view=msvc-160) Pasamos al código:

En la parte donde comienza tu menú, puedes agregar el `do{}` y el `while()` antes del `system("pause")`; encapsulándolo de esta manera:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a = 10000;

main ()
{
    int q = 60, w = 120, e= 200;
    int c;
    int l;
    
    do{
        printf ("\n\nSEDAN");
        printf ("\n <<60 litros>>");
        printf ("\nIngresa el auto a llenar:\n");
        scanf("%d", &l);
        
        switch (l)
        {
            case 1: 
            
                c=a-q;
                printf("%d", c);
                break;
            
            case 2:
            
                c=c-w;
                printf("%d", c);
                break;
            
            default:
            puts("Algo fallo");
            break;
        }
    }while(l!=3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Por cierto, en tus `case` veo que les agregaste corchetes `{}` los cuales no son necesarios, además de que, para que funcione, debes obtener la opción pedida al usuario: he cambiado en el `switch(1)` por `switch(l)` para que puedas trabajar con el bucle `do` así que me di esa libertad de corregirlo.

Comment: Hace lo que necesitas pero, me queda una duda ¿Qué estas intentando hacer con este programa? Ya que en el case 2, arroja un error, dando números negativos

Comment: Estoy intentando simular una bomba de gasolina que se esta vaciando (con las opciones swicht) estoy probando con el case 1 para que pregunte al usuario si desea llenar un sedan con 60 litros de gasolina (q), esta en teoría restaría el valor de la bomba de gasolina(a) para llenar el auto, el resultado "c" (a-q) restablecería el valor de "a" y permitiria segur restando

Comment: Te recomiendo que a tus variables les pongas nombres que se comprendan, por si otro programador (si, ya eres un programador en formación :) ) le toca leer tu código, no sufra tanto a la hora de entender la lógica. Suerte, bro, que si se puede :)

Comment: Muchas gracias :3